# Pass formGroupName to the child component

Tags: angular, forms

I have the following form:

```
form = this.fb.group({
  a: this.fb.group({
    b: ''
  })
});
```

I would like to split the form into multiple components, like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-a formGroupName="a"></app-a>
</form>
```

But it's not possible since my `AComponent` does not implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

I know about `ControlContainer`, but it gives me the form itself. I just want to take a FormGroup by its name. I tried to create a directive that will take the control from the `ControlContainer` by its name, but I cannot understand how to pass it from the directive to my component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormGroupName]',
  providers: [{
    provide: FormGroup,
    useFactory: (controlContainer: ControlContainer, {name}: FormGroupNameDirective) => controlContainer.control[name] as FormGroup, // This doesn't work — FormGroupNameDirective is undefined
    deps: [ControlContainer, FormGroupNameDirective]
  }]
})
export class FormGroupNameDirective {

  @Input('appFormGroupName') name: string;

  constructor(@Host() @SkipSelf() parent: ControlContainer) {
  }

}
```

I could use the `ControlContainer` in my `AComponent`, but I've got too much similar components and I don't want to copy/paste this logic in each of them. I also don't want to implement `ControlValueAccessor` for the same reasons.

I tried to use `NgControl`, but have the same result.

How can I achieve this logic in the most shortest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `form` and the `controlName` to your children component.

In your example it would look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <app-a controlName="a" [form]="form"></app-a>
</form>
```

Them in the AppA component:

```
// .ts
@Input controlName: string;
@Input form: FormControl;

// .html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input [formControlName]="controlName"/>
</div>
```

Here is a example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmhryc

Comment: It is easier for me to pass the control itself. And this works. The thing is that I only want to pass the control name.